# Python IRC Bot link resolver?

Tags: python, hyperlink, bots, irc

So I haven't been able to find a bunch of information on the subject, but I'm looking for an example to resolve a given link when it is posted to the IRC channel. Any tips/examples?

Comment: You mean like get it's title, etc? [ircbot.py](https://bitbucket.org/circuits/circuits/src/tip/examples/ircbot.py) is a good starting point (*Disclaimer:* I'm the developer)

Comment: Yeah pretty much. Also I have the framework for the bot programmed already, but am simply looking for advice on it getting the headers and passing them to the channel so you can get an idea of what the link is before clicking on it :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a quick example that does exactly what you're after.

Feel free to use this as a basis for your needs!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from re import findall

from circuits import Component
from circuits.ne t.events import connect
from circuits.net.sockets import TCPClient
from circuits.protocols.irc import ERR_NICKNAMEINUSE
from circuits.protocols.irc import RPL_ENDOFMOTD, ERR_NOMOTD
from circuits.protocols.irc import IRC, PRIVMSG, USER, NICK, JOIN

from requests import get
from lxml.html import fromstring


class Bot(Component):

    def init(self, host, port=6667):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port

        TCPClient().register(self)
        IRC().register(self)

    def ready(self, component):
        self.fire(connect(self.host, self.port))

    def connected(self, host, port):
        self.fire(USER("circuits", host, host, "Test circuits IRC Bot"))
        self.fire(NICK("circuits"))

    def numeric(self, source, target, numeric, args, message):
        if numeric == ERR_NICKNAMEINUSE:
            self.fire(NICK("%s_" % args))
        if numeric in (RPL_ENDOFMOTD, ERR_NOMOTD):
            self.fire(JOIN("#circuits"))

    def message(self, source, target, message):
        if target[0] == "#":
            urls = findall("http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+", message)  # noqa
            if urls:
                url = urls[0]
                response = get(url)
                if response.status_code == 200:
                    doc = fromstring(response.text)
                    title = doc.cssselect("title")
                    if title:
                        title = title[0].text.strip()
                        self.fire(
                            PRIVMSG(
                                target,
                                "URL: {0:s} Title: {1:s}".format(
                                    url,
                                    title
                                )
                            )
                        )
        else:
            self.fire(PRIVMSG(source[0], message))


bot = Bot("irc.freenode.net")

bot.run()
```

You will need:

- [circuits](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/circuits)
- [requests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests)
- [lxml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml)
- [cssselect](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cssselect)

You can install these via:

```
pip install circuits cssselect lxml requests
```

*Disclaimer:* I'm the developer of circuits

**Updated:** Tested to be working as expected.